# Visually Nested Blocks

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Does any one know if textmate has a visual way to denote a nested block?  I just started using coffee script (which uses tabbed nesting) and thought it would be great to have something similar to this:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/section_thirdlevel_highlight.png

Would it be possible to write a plugin that does something along these lines in textmate 2?

Thanks!

Edit: After some more searching I found this is sometimes called "indentation guides".  I still havne't found any way to do this in textmate 2 but sublime text has the feature on by default.